# Where is the putty login info saved?

Tags: 16.04, ssh, putty

I use putty for SSH connections to other servers. I save the login information within putty.

Now I am setting up new client PCs where I would like to replicate the login info, so that I do not have to type the addresses, settings, username etc... and save it repeatedly.

[image: Putty window]

**Where is the login information and settings saved for putty?**

Comment: According to this [post](http://superuser.com/questions/591576/export-putty-settings-or-sessions-from-a-linux-to-another-linux) its stored in `~/.putty/sessions`. check there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in `~/.putty/sessions` and if you want you can fool around with copying that around between machines. However, this is not a very effective strategy to manage your access to the servers. It will require manually coping credentails and in the event of someone getting access to your logins it will be harder to revoke access to those credentials.

What many do instead is have a single SSH key you use that represents your identity, usually your only/default SSH key:

```
 cat ~/.ssh/*.pub
 # If you do not have a key generate one with ssh-keygen command
 # only enter a password if you want to encrypt the key (optional)
```

This will print out your public key. It's a single line of text that allows other servers to guarantee that the incoming connection is from that SSH key. Log into the remote server (for the first time using a password or local terminal) then add the public key line from earlier to a file called `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` (create this file and any directories if it doesn't exist)

Now just about every area of Linux will understand the remote `sftp://` and `ssh://` connections to that server and negotiate them automatically without prompting you for anything (unless you encrypted your keyfile earlier) This means File Browser (nautilus) and terminals will simply "just work"